# Is there a way to stop viewchanges till a block of code is completed?

Tags: angular

I have two statements leading to changes in the view:

```
statement1; // changes a databinding
statement2; // is an asynchronous call which does several changes
```

I would like both changes to be applied to the view at the same time. Currently statement1 finishes, applies its changes to the view while statement2 is still processing. So the change from statement1 is visible a few milliseconds before the change from statement2 is visible which does not look good. Is there a way to stop viewchanges till both statements are complete?

Comment: Is there a concrete example to work with? A sample stackblitz replicating the issue would be really helpful. :) Would it be possible to create one and share it across? Thanks

Comment: Please see [mcve] and perhaps make an example with https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can consider detaching the view from angular's change detection for a moment.

1. Inject ChangeDetectorRef in your components

`constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }`

2. disable change detection before your statement1 and re-enable it after statement2 is completed.

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detach();

statement1; // changes a databinding

statement2; // is an asynchronous call which does several changes

this.changeDetectorRef.reattach();
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is to use a resolver to get the information for statement 2. Once you have the information from statement 2, then you would want to go to the route and show the information from both statement 1 and 2.

https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

If you didn't want to wait for statement 2 before you went to the new route, then you would need to make both statements async and wait to show the results of statement 1 until statement 2 is complete.